# HTML <a href="#hash"> in AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs, angular-ui-router, hashref

I have an issue with the `<a href="#">` in my AngularJS app.

My main issue is on the:

`<a href="#menu-toggle" class="btn btn-default" id="menu-toggle"><em class="fa fa-bars"></em></a>`

**navigation.html** -> this is a `template` of `navigation` `directive`.

```
<nav class="sidebar col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-lg-3 col-xl-2 bg-faded sidebar-style-1">
<h1 class="site-title"><a href="index.html"><em class="fa fa-rocket"></em> Brand.name</a></h1>

<a href="#menu-toggle" class="btn btn-default" id="menu-toggle"><em class="fa fa-bars"></em></a>

<ul class="nav nav-pills flex-column sidebar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active" href="index.html"><em class="fa fa-dashboard"></em> Dashboard <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
</ul>

<a href="#" class="logout-button"><em class="fa fa-power-off"></em> Signout</a></nav>
```

**index.html**

```
<body ng-app="test" class="body-bg" ng-style="bgimg" ui-view>
</body>
```

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module("test", ["ui.router");

app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
    $stateProvider

        // login route
        .state("login", {
        url:"/",
        controller: "LoginController",
        templateUrl: "pages/login/login.html"
        })
        // admin route
        .state("admin", {
        url:"/admin",
        controller: "AdminController",
        templateUrl: "pages/admin/admin.html"
        })
```

And currently I am doing a SPA routing using `ui-sref` of `ui-router`.
The problem is everytime I click the `button`, I get redirected to the default `state` `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');`.

How I can do something similar to that **HTML** `href="#"` with AngularJS `ui-sref`?

Or is there other ways?

Comment: are you using a plugin for your menu? Jquery or Boostrap?

Comment: yes, same jquery and bootstrap.

Answer (score 1):

if you have jQuery (which you probably do) 
inside your head tag...

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('[href="#menu-toggle"]').click(function(event){

             event.preventDefault();
        })

    });
</script>
```

Basically keeps the link from routing via window navigation.
You can easily test by pasting this code into your browser console..

```
$('[href="#menu-toggle"]').click(function(event){

         event.preventDefault();
    })
```

Comment: where do I insert that line?

Comment: you can put in in the <head> tag inside of a script tag. let me update my answer...

Comment: I tested it, but it is redirecting. But I will explore more. Maybe I just didn't do it right. Thanks, appreciate it.

Comment: I gave you the wrong selector. Please see my updated answer

Comment: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [href=#menu-toggle]

Comment: Try putting single quotes around '#menu-toggle'

Comment: Actually double quote because we are using single quotes on the selector. I'll update answer...

Comment: it's not working. Okay, I will create a plnkr and I will put the link on my question. Appreciate your trying to help, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

from the code in the question I can say that, the normal usage of href will result in redirection so you need to use `data-target`, can you please try this?

```
<a  data-target="#menu-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" class="btn btn-default"><em class="fa fa-bars"></em></a>
```

**JSFiddle:** [here](https://jsfiddle.net/v4odw1kp/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it's not working for me. I thought it would be working as I saw in your provided plnkr. But sadly not. Appreciate your help.

Comment: No, it's not happening but It's not collapsing.

Comment: @Marksmanship It should have worked as I have provided in the JSFiddle, Share with me a JSFiddle the issue, if you want to use this method to solve your problem :)

Comment: Okay, I will create a plnkr and I will put the link on my question. Appreciate your trying to help, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of `href` and `ng-click` to solve your problem.

```
<a href="" class="logout-button" ng-click="signOut()"><em class="fa fa-power-off"></em> Signout</a></nav>
```

Where `signOut()` is a function on your controller.

Answer (score -1):

1.Just remove the href tag completely from your anchor tag. It's still a perfectly valid tag without it. (or)  href="javascript:void(0);"

for your reference: [Angular-UI-Router: should i avoid href with ui-router?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43155308/angular-ui-router-should-i-avoid-href-with-ui-router)